# Which hook runs first(init,... or ???)

Tags: hooks

For example,any "naked" code, i.e.:

```
IF ($_POST) then....,
```

runs directly, before any WP action. 
for example, this runs later (even with point 1):

```
add_action('init','my_function',1);
```

I want to execute my code before any WP action starts. Which hook executes at first?

Comment: Maybe this: `if(condition) add_action($tag, $callback_function, $priority);` ? in your case: `if(isset($_POST["data"])) add_action('init','my_functionnn',1);`

Comment: Small hint. The plugin Debug Objects list the hooks in his order, helpful to find and understanding hooks.

Comment: Really? You are asking essentially the same question twice after you got such excellent answers the last time?

Comment: @toscho , probably I have forgot that.. thanks.. however, this was a bit different thing, to know, if there exists something, that runs before "NAKED" code (which is put in functions.php or plugin)...

Answer (score 0):

Generally `after_setup_theme` is the first action hook available to themes, triggered immediately after the active theme's `functions.php` file is loaded. At this stage, the current user is not yet authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

`init` runs before `admin_init`

There's different ways to verify this using code or a plugin.